# Does C# require .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

I'm new to C# (but not to programming) and I was wondering: do C# programs always require .NET, or are there ways to avoid dependencies and make the application independent?

Comment: As of now there is no static compiler for C# and if one would exist it would have to remove some features that can be provided more efficiently through the CLR.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the .Net framework is installed by default on most versions of Windows in use (you may stumble across someone using NT4, or something, but they then have bigger problems in terms of the whole operating system no longer being supported)

Comment: @the_drow I beg to differ, see [Mono AoT Compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:AOT), notably section *Performance considerations*. That said, notably absent from AoT compiled binaries are "dynamic" features like in `System.Reflection`.

Comment: i also am new in c# and many times using C so i am finding this dissucion of interesting

Answer (score 18):

Yes C# always requires the .NET runtime.

If you are worried about other platforms there is [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) which will allow .NET applications to run on platforms other than Windows (i.e. Linux) using the Mono runtime.

C# code is compiled into CIL code which is a platform-independent instruction set, I quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

> During compilation of .NET programming
>   languages, the source code is
>   translated into CIL code rather than
>   platform or processor-specific object
>   code. CIL is a CPU- and
>   platform-independent instruction set
>   that can be executed in any
>   environment supporting the Common
>   Language Infrastructure, such as the
>   .NET runtime on Windows, or the
>   cross-platform Mono runtime.

Comment: I don't understand why people think Mono makes C# cross-platform. Sure, it helps... but the recommended way to do GUI apps in .NET is now WPF, and there are no current plans to add that to Mono. That seems to make it quite clear that your WPF application is going nowhere else but Microsoft OSes (unless Silverlight is good enough for you).

Comment: Mono has a Ahead Of Time compiler. They used that in MonoTouch to create self-contained, native code and comply with iOS App Store rules.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify. If you TARGET Mono, then you can write cross-platform .NET apps. If you don't consider it up front and use the latest and greatest .NET platform and the current best practices... it's not going to be likely to work on Mono.

Comment: @darron, there are loads of things to do besides heavy-duty WPF apps. Think server-side. Even then, WPF is not a replacement for WinForms but an complement. That said, there is no silver bullet.

Comment: i have read also of c# nativity compiler of the remotesoft.com

Answer (score 6):

A [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) runtime/interpreter is required, but it doesn't have to be [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).

Currently there is one other CLI interpreter, [MONO](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

C# isn't compiled to native code, and therefore the computer can't read it. You need the .Net framework to convert the so called bytecode (the code that the C# compiler compiles to, CLI) can be converted by the Just In Time compiler of the .Net framework.

Mono is an alternative framework, and it can also run C#. It is supported on more platforms then then the .Net framework (that only supports Windows).

So yes, either the .Net framework or the Mono runtime is needed to run C# applications, new versions of Windows automatically install and update the .Net framework.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently .NET runtime is not required, see MonoTouch for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. C# is just a programming language, and just like any other programming: It can be compiled in any way you can think of: That includes compiling without .NET. In fact, the MONO project (C# for a lot of platforms) does just that.

There are some other commercial compilers available that will pretend to compile your application without .NET , but they just stick .NET in your executable: which is useless, slow and just stupid.

Any other way to use C# without .NET or MONO would be more of an educational experience than a practical solution. As for what the education experience is worth: If you have the time, I would definitely recommend trying something like it when you have a bit more experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just as C programs typically require a C runtime, C# programs require the common language runtime.

Comment: oh ho ho, I didn't know there was a C runtime.  Interesting.

Comment: -1 That's a horribly misleading answer, because many C programs *don't* use the runtime.  I can compile C programs to run directly on the hardware (machine instructions), and even in-line assembly in a C program.  To my knowledge, there is no machine code generating compiler for C#.  A better comparison would have been Java, which also relies on an interpreter (and JIT, etc, etc).

Comment: C does **not** require a runtime!

Comment: Well, the "C runtime library" (as in MSVCRT) is not remotely the same thing as the "common language runtime". Sure, they share a word, but the first just refers to a standardized function library, while the second refers to a platform + toolchain + virtual machine + ...

Comment: Inline asm isn't C, it's asm.  And who said C required a runtime?  I didn't, I said that C _programs_ *typically* require a runtime.  Which many do, even old firmware written 20+ years ago.

Comment: C programs compile into native machine code, which are executed practically verbatim by the CPU. The only thing standing between the program and the CPU is the OS kernel which is little more than a security guard. The fact that a standard set of libraries may be required for a C program to work properly does not mean it requires a "runtime". C# programs compile into an "intermediate language" (MSIL), and are executed by a platform-specific loader that provides a "sandbox" within which the user code does its work.

Comment: If a C program "requires a standard set of libraries called the C Runtime Libraries," then one might even say that the C program "requires a C runtime."

Comment: answer has good comparisons and argumentations,, the .net is library but bigger

Comment: @Greg - The difference is that the C program only needs MSVCRT because MSVCRT provides hardware hooks the developer would otherwise have to implement himself from scratch, and secondarily to enforce some basic OS-level security (allowing the OS to "kill" the program if it tries to break the OS rules). You can write and compile a C program that requires only a computer to run it. MSVCRT does NOT translate the compiled code into something the CPU can understand. MSVCRT does NOT provide garbage collection. MSVCRT does NOT make a program targeting a Linux kernel work in Windows.

Comment: @KeithS:  All true and also completely beside the point.  The fact that a CRT is thinner than the CLR doesn't change the fact that it's a runtime library that the vast majority of C programs will require to run.  You're getting hung up on implementation details that aren't relevant to the point at hand.  Who cares _what_ the runtime does?  Most C programs require some flavor of C runtime, and most C# programs require the CLR.

Comment: @Greg D - Not most - ALL C# programs require the CLR (or a workalike) in order to run, and as I said before, that is not a requirement of a C program. C does NOT require a "runtime" to provide a sandbox in which to work and to give it parentally-approved things to work with; it MAY require tools it does not itself have, but which it knows about and loads into its own memory space. There is a BIG difference here; it's not just "implementation details".

Comment: I don't understand what you could possible be arguing about.  There is nothing untrue about the statement that most C programs require some flavor of C runtime.

Comment: A C program needs a runtime the same way ALL programs require SOMETHING to load them into memory and point the CPU's execution register at the first instruction. The executable loader of an OS, or the virtual machine in multitasking OSes, is NOT a "runtime" as the term is commonly understood. Even beyond that, C programs only need MSVCRT the same way ANY program might need hooks to a standard code library. A "runtime" infers a managed code environment that performs translation of IL to native code. Java requires a runtime. C# requires a runtime. C does NOT.

Comment: And on top of that, when you have a "runtime", you have to ask "well, what runs the runtime?". LONG before you get to the root of this recursion, you find "native" programs that are run in a "runtime" (VM) only because they are run in a multitasking OS and so cannot have the computer's undivided attention. At some level, you need a program that does NOT run with any external help whatsoever. This is the kernel, and most are written in C/C++. Device drivers, which get absolutely nothing for free, are written in C if not ASM. Count all of these, and the balance tips considerably.

Comment: the C runtime has no helpful comparison with the C# runtime in the context of the question asked. this answer is not helpful; -1.